# Way to fix this algorithm

Tags: java

This code will only work if I hit both enemies with collision (walk into them) or if i kill both (with bullets) (i.e. I run into the first enemy and the second or I kill both with a bullet), but if i kill the first enemy (with bullet) then run into the 2nd (with collision) my hp wont go down. Any tips??

```
 if (d.intersects(r1))
    {
            en.isAlive = false;
            hitfirst = true;


}
if (d.intersects(r2))
{
        en2.isAlive = false;


}
if (d.intersects(r2)  && hitfirst == false)
         hitmang(hit);
p.hitting = true;

if (d.intersects(r1) && en.visible == true && en.isAlive == false && !p.hitting)
{


    hitmang(hit);
    p.hitting = true;
}



if (d.intersects(r2) && en.visible == true && en.isAlive == false && !p.hitting)
{  

      hitmang(hit);
      p.hitting = true;
}

if (!d.intersects(r1) && d.intersects(r2) && en2.visible == true && !p.hitting)  {
hitmang(hit);
p.hitting = true;
        }
    if (!d.intersects(r1) && !d.intersects(r2)){
       p.hitting = false;

    }
```

Boundaries of my enemies

```
public Rectangle getBounds() // ghost is 114 x 134
    {
        return new Rectangle(x, y, 114, 134);
    }
```

Enemies

```
en = new Enemy(700, 150);
en2 = new Enemy (980, 150);
```

Hitmangs

```
private void hitmang(int x) // x=25
{
     p.user_hp = p.user_hp - x;
}
```

Comment: `this code will only work if I hit both enemies with collision or if i kill both` - Who are your enemies, and why do you want to kill them ? Please provide more information, your question is incomplete

Comment: I added more info + I want to kill them because thats the objective (hope that helps, and thanks for helping me out).

Answer (score 1):

@user29698

I posted in your previous post how to use ArrayLists... I suggest you use that method when dealing with multiple enemies.

[How would I put enemies into an ArrayList](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14064426/how-would-i-put-enemies-into-an-arraylist/14064687#14064687)

Post the hitmang method on here...

You need to start using System.out.println("blah blah blah"); to help debugging!

place that line in between your parenthesis.

IF it prints it to the console then it's not the ".intersects" method that isn't working properly. It may be your hit method...

Comment: added it and ill try your idea, thanks for the other answer :D                  edit: tried your idea and it is not printing so im assuming that the algorithm is the problem.

Comment: If it's not printing then I'm guessing you're right :) check your booleans now (take them away one by one) to test which or IF they are the problem